# MySQL upgrade from 5.1.11 to 5.1.72

Tags: mysql

I have an old version of MySQL Server 5.1.11. I would like to update it by keeping the same main version. What is the best way to upgrade from version 5.1.11 to version 5.1.72?

It seems that 5.1.72 is the last stable version of 5.1

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake: the current version is 5.0.51b, so I would like to upgrade to 5.0.96

Comment: please mention your operating system

Comment: WIndows Server 2003

Answer (score 0):

There are downloads available in the [MySQL Archive Downloads page](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

[image]

Comment: ok, I saw it. But.. I must just download and install? These are installations, I don't lost all my settings and data?

Comment: take a backup of both just in case. Install in a test environment with existing data and see what happens.